# Checking if number is in range javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a built-in way in JavaScript to check if number is between two others? I use `if(x < i && x > l)`, but hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Define "better". You're already using a "built-in way".

Comment: Try the function that I proposed [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354555/check-if-number-is-in-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **won't** get it done faster or better as Felix Kling said in the other post.

However, you can create a prototype method if you use it a lot:

```
Number.prototype.inRange = function (a, b) {
    return this >= a && this <= b;
};

var num = 8;
console.log(num.inRange(7, 8));// true
num = 4;
console.log(num.inRange(7, 8));// false
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a built-in way in JavaScript to check if number is between two others?

I imagine you thought about something similar to Python's `l < x < h`. No there is not.
`x < h && x > l` is the built-in way.

Answer (score 1):

Not a built-in function, but nothing wrong with not being built in:

```js
function inRange(low, num, high, inclusive) {
  inclusive = (typeof inclusive === "undefined") ? false : inclusive;
  if (inclusive && num >= low && num <= high) return true;
  if (num > low && num < high) return true;
  return false;
}

console.log(inRange(3, 7, 12));      // true
console.log(inRange(3, 7, 7, true)); // true
console.log(inRange(3, 3, 7, true)); // true

console.log(inRange(3, 7, 7));       // false
console.log(inRange(3, 3, 7));       // false
console.log(inRange(3, 9, 7));       // false
console.log(inRange(3, 9, 7, true)); // false
```