# Check if number is in range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking if my number coming from a input field is in range

```
function timeCheck(){

        var time = $.trim($('#enterTime').value());
            Number.prototype.between = function(min,max){
                return this > min && this < max;
            };
            if ((time).between(1,9)){
                    alert("test");
                }
            }
```

But somehow it does not work .. the alert is never triggered

Thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: `if((time).between(1,9)) /* <- parenthesis here*/ {`

Comment: @X.L.Ant hmm still not triggered

Comment: Appear missing closing `)` at `if` condition ?

Comment: @palaѕн no that all wrong it still does not work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @Daniel's answer, there are two other errors: first, `$('#enterTime').value()` is not a valid jQuery function, should be `$('#enterTime').val()`. Second, you need to convert your value to type `Number`. Otherwise, you will be trying to access the `between` property of a string, which doesn't exist. The final code would be:

```
function timeCheck(){
    var time = new Number($.trim($('#enterTime').val()));
    Number.prototype.between = function(min,max){
        return this > min && this < max;
    };
    if(time.between(1,9)){
        alert("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a closing bracket but a missing parenthesis:

```
if((time).between(1,9){
```

Should be:

```
if ((time).between(1,9)){
```

or

```
if (time.between(1,9)){
```

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d8y1t4nk/)
Try the following code

```
function timeCheck(){
    var time = parseInt($.trim($('#enterTime').val()),10);
        Number.prototype.between = function(min,max){
            var num = parseInt(this,10);

            return num >= min && num <= max; 
        }
            if((time).between(1,9)){
                alert("test");
            }
}
```

The issue was with type conversion object **time** was not of type **Number**.

Hope it helps .....

Answer (score 0):

This question was already asked: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029409/how-to-check-if-an-integer-is-within-a-range/21368722#21368722)

Try the function I propose (in the mentioned post it was for PHP) that is valid for increasing or decreasing ranges and not limited to integers:

```
function between(n, a, b)
{
    var chk= false;
   if ((a==n)&&(b==n)){
      chk = true;
    }else{
      chk = (n-a)*(n-b)<0;
    }
    return chk;
}
```

The function TRUE if n is between a and b